# applying sql transactions on non consecutive steps

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, transactions

I have the following scenario of SQL statements :

```
DELETE FROM T1
DELETE FROM T2
DELETE FROM T3
DELETE FROM T4
DELETE FROM T5
```

In above case I need to achieve:

1. If the next SQL statement fails, a rollback of previous statement would occur, in case of success it will move to its next statement.
2. But for step 5, I need to rollback Step 3, committing the step 4 as it is.

Any inputs, kindly advice.

Comment: So why aren't steps 3 and 4 reordered?

Comment: Due to some business logic, we cannot change the sequence of statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server there is no such thing as nested transactions. But you can do it with a bit of error-handling orchestration.

This sample code simply re-issues the delete command from T4 again in case of errors were encountered on the T5 command.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- (use temp table, since table vars do not participate in transactions)
CREATE TABLE #T1(C int);
CREATE TABLE #T2(C int);
CREATE TABLE #T3(C int);
CREATE TABLE #T4(C int);
CREATE TABLE #T5(C int);

INSERT INTO #T1 SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO #T2 SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO #T3 SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO #T4 SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO #T5 SELECT 1;

BEGIN TRY 

    BEGIN TRAN TR1;

    DELETE FROM #T1;
    DELETE FROM #T2;
    DELETE FROM #T3;    
    DELETE FROM #T4;
    --select 1/0 as 'forced error @ stage1';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'error @stage1';
    PRINT 'rollback @stage1';

    ROLLBACK TRAN TR1;  
    RETURN;
END CATCH

BEGIN TRY
    DELETE FROM #T5;
    select 1/0 as 'forced error @stage2';
    COMMIT TRAN TR1;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'error @stage2';  
    ROLLBACK TRAN TR1;  

    BEGIN TRY
        print 'redo delete T4'
        BEGIN TRAN TR2;
        DELETE FROM #t4;
        --select 1/0 as 'forced error @redo delete';
        COMMIT TRAN TR2;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN TR2;
        PRINT 'second chance delete from T4 failed';    
    END CATCH

END CATCH

select count(*) as count,'T1' as 'table' from #T1
union all
select count(*) as count,'T2' as 'table' from #T2
union all
select count(*) as count,'T3' as 'table' from #T3
union all
select count(*) as count,'T4' as 'table' from #T4
union all
select count(*) as count,'T5' as 'table' from #T5

DROP TABLE #T1;
DROP TABLE #T2;
DROP TABLE #T3;
DROP TABLE #T4;
DROP TABLE #T5;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with **SAVE POINTS** and **GOTO** within **TRY- CATCH** blocks:

This do the both goals you wanted in the question:

Test it each time with uncommenting specific "`SELECT 1/0`" statement:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #T1(ID int);
CREATE TABLE #T2(ID int);
CREATE TABLE #T3(ID int);
CREATE TABLE #T4(ID int);
CREATE TABLE #T5(ID int);

INSERT INTO #T1 SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO #T2 SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO #T3 SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO #T4 SELECT 1;
INSERT INTO #T5 SELECT 1;

BEGIN TRAN 
        BEGIN TRY
            DELETE FROM #T1
            --SELECT 1/0
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRAN
            GOTO LAST2
        END CATCH

    SAVE TRAN pice1
        BEGIN TRY
            DELETE FROM #T2
            --SELECT 1/0
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRAN 
            GOTO LAST2
        END CATCH

    SAVE TRAN pice2
        BEGIN TRY
            DELETE FROM #T3
            --SELECT 1/0
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRAN pice1
            GOTO LAST
        END CATCH

    SAVE TRAN pice3
        BEGIN TRY
            DELETE FROM #T4
            --SELECT 1/0
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRAN pice2
            GOTO LAST
        END CATCH

    SAVE TRAN pice4
        BEGIN TRY
            DELETE FROM #T5
            SELECT 1/0
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRAN pice2
            DELETE FROM #T4
            GOTO LAST
        END CATCH

LAST:
COMMIT TRAN
LAST2:
SELECT COUNT(*) CT,'T1' [TABLE] FROM #T1
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) CT,'T2' [TABLE] FROM #T2
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) CT,'T3' [TABLE] FROM #T3
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) CT,'T4' [TABLE] FROM #T4
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) CT,'T5' [TABLE] FROM #T5

DROP TABLE #T1;
DROP TABLE #T2;
DROP TABLE #T3;
DROP TABLE #T4;
DROP TABLE #T5;
```